# How to substitute the script source when visiting a website?

Tags: javascript, html, src

Here's a specific problem: 
I found a website like this:
**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
(function(){
    var x = 2;
    alert(x)
})();
```

I wish I could change x to 5 (so that it alerts 5), however I can't do it from the console because I can't access the anonymous function and because the alert would have already been executed before I could change anything.

Normal solution would be to change x to 5 in the script itself however the script is not on my server so I can't change it directly. 
I can of course modify it locally so how can I make it so that every time I visit this website, the local script is executed instead original script? (I use Firefox by the way)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: why do you want/need to change the script to 5?

Comment: Hmm.... Ajax is one way.....

Comment: [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/?src=hp-dl-mostpopular) is a way to run userscripts, used to enhance a sites feature. Perhaps this can help you modify the original script